# Android - list view and calendar view inside scroll view not showing all items

Tags: java, android

I have calendar view and list view inside scroll view.but all list items not showing. only one item is showing. please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: Please Read **[Necessary things to read while asking  a good question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** And also read how to create [mcve]

Comment: Please share your code - Adapter and Activity so that we can help you resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Use this following on place of `NonScrollListView`

```
public class NonScrollListView extends ListView 
{

 public NonScrollListView(Context context) 
 {
    super(context);
 }
 public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
 {
    super(context, attrs);
 }
 public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
 {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
 }
 @Override
 public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
 {
    int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
    params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
 }
}

<yourPackageName.NonScrollListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/list_view"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

It'll solve your issue.